# How can I check or uncheck QStandrdItem's check box in "PySide2 QStandardItemModel" with mouse click and drag?

Tags: python, pyside2, qstandarditemmodel

what I need in this case is "uncheck or check" the items in QListView with mouse hold and press

[image]

I've added Items with check boxes , I need to change the state of the items (check or uncheck) for multi items with just press and hold , like making multi selection .

```py
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import sys


class items_List(QListView):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self,items):
        QListView.__init__(self)

        #self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.model.itemChanged.connect(self.on_itemChanged)

        self.items = items
        self.add_items_(self.items)

        self.show()


    def add_items_(self,all_items=None):
        self.active_items = []
        if all_items == None:
            return
        for item in all_items:
            #self.model.appendRow(str(i))
            self.item = QStandardItem(str(item))
            self.item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable)

            self.item.setData(QVariant(Qt.Checked), Qt.CheckStateRole)

            self.model.appendRow(self.item)
            self.active_items.append(str(item))

    def selected_item(self):
        print "Selected "


    @pyqtSlot(QStandardItem)
    def on_itemChanged(self,  item):
        state = ['UNCHECKED', 'TRISTATE',  'CHECKED'][item.checkState()]

        if state == 'UNCHECKED':
            self.active_items.remove(item.text())

        else:
            if item.text() not in self.active_items:
                self.active_items.append(str(item.text()))

        print self.active_items

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    items = [1001,1002,1003,1004,1005]
    win = items_List(items)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: could you explain in more detail what you want

Comment: I need to use mouse to check or uncheck multi items in one click

Comment: explain yourself better, that's not detailed, what action (s) should the user do? **Please be detailed**

Comment: click and drag the check boxes on the left of the items to change the state for those  items

Comment: mmm, friend I don't understand your explanation (maybe someone will understand you). Bye

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to toggle the items' checkstate by mouse dragging on the checkboxes. Is it right? If that's so, you should provide us with more information, and possibly a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've got so far (even if it doesn't work). Specifically, we need to know if that's a table or a list view, and how you create the UI and set the model.